# reader.readasdataurl is not working in for loop javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

In my requirement all file uploaded files need to be converted into base64 format and push them values into one object. I got the proper output sometimes, sometimes I didn't get the value it sends an empty value. Below is my code.

```
var fileControls = $('input[type="file"]');
var FilesObj = [];
for (var a = 0; a < fileControls.length; a++) {
    var files = fileControls[a].files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        var sdd = fileControls[a].files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var Obj1 = new Object();
        // $(e.target).attr('id')
        reader.readAsDataURL(sdd);
        reader.onloadend = function (x,y) {
            Obj1.Key = x;
            // reader.readAsDataURL(y);
            var valRes = y.result;
            Obj1.Value = valRes;
            FilesObj.push(Obj1);
        }
        reader.onloadend(fileControls[a].id, reader);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onload` event with param instead.

```js
var FilesObj=[]; 
function GetFiles(){
var fileControls = $('input[type="file"]');
            for (var a = 0; a < fileControls.length; a++) {
                var files = fileControls[a].files;
                if (files.length > 0) {
                    var file = fileControls[a].files[0];
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    var Obj1 = new Object();
                    // $(e.target).attr('id')
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);                 
                    reader.onload = (function(f,id) {
                    return function(e) {
                    // Here you can use `e.target.result` or `this.result`
                    // `f.id`and `f.name`.
                     Obj1.Key = id;
                                var valRes = this.result;
                                Obj1.Value = valRes;
                                FilesObj.push(Obj1);
                    };
                })(file,fileControls[a].id);
               }
            }
    }
    
    function ViewFiles (){
    $.each(FilesObj,function(i,obj){
    var $img = $("<img>").prop("id","img"+obj.Key).attr("src",obj.Value).prop("width","100").prop("height","100");
    $("#divImages").append($img);
    });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file1">
<input type="file" id="file2">
<input type="file" id="file3">
<input type="file" id="file4">
<input type="file" id="file5">
<br>
<br>
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="GetFiles()">Get Files</button>
<button type="button" onclick="ViewFiles()">View Files</button>

<br>
<br>
<div id="divImages"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post your logic to send the values where you are trying to?

Comment: reader.readAsDataURL(sdd);
                        reader.onload = function () {
                            Obj1.Key = fileControls[a].id;
                            var valRes = reader.result;
                            Obj1.Value = valRes;
                            FilesObj.push(Obj1);
                        }
                        reader.onload();

Comment: all are same, instead of passing values i am assigning values directly. plz check once

Comment: i am getting empty value in this line of code  Obj1.Value = reader.result;

Comment: reader.readAsDataURL(sdd); this line executes give result value sometimes its skips then only i got reader.result value is empty.

Comment: on your code only try to debug  with f12 someties onload function called sometimes it skiped. plz check once

Comment: Working perfect every time. Have tried it on different browser?

Comment: code was not executing after the below line   return function(e) { inside code not execute}